Sending a small audio file to a large number of mobile apps - Bluetooth or WiFi?
I am developing a voice messaging solution that sends a small (approx. 200kB) audio MP3 file from a central "transmission" site to apps installed on a large number of smartphones located close together. Apps will receive this message over a local wireless connection - either WiFi or Bluetooth, since both of these are supported by the majority of devices.
This will form part of a disaster alerting system that is designed to provide verbal instruction to a very large number of people (many thousands) located in close proximity at an evacuation centre, and at times when cellular services or internet are not available.
The questions I have are:

Can BLE or Classic Bluetooth perform broadcasting (sending 200kB) to a large number of devices at once?
Would broadcasting over a WiFi WLAN connection provide a better architecture?

I have experimented with BLE5 Advertising. When the BLE 5.0 tx-power is set to +20dBm and connected to a 10dBi gain omni antenna, this does provide the RF coverage area I require. However I suspect that BLE can only support one device paired at a time, so the message would have to be sent sequentially which could take an excessive amount of time.

Seems you want to use the new Bluetooth LE Audio, also known as Auracast™ Broadcast Audio

BLE can support more than one device, but there might be a limit coming from the hardware you are using. BLE Mesh might be a solution for your scenario, this would allow you to reach devices that are not in reach of your central site, but are in range of devices that are in range of the site themselves.

Unfortunately neither classic Bluetooth/BLE nor WiFi are currently optimized for this application, as each of these technologies have their limitations. With classic Bluetooth, broadcasting is not supported in the first place so this is an immediate elimination. With BLE, broadcasting is supported through sending advert packets, but most devices do not have the new BLE5 or BLE audio features, which means that the maximum advertising payload is 31 bytes, and therefore it would take a long time for your 200kB to be sent. WiFi also doesn't support broadcasting inherintly or at least the infrastructure doesn't allow for it.
As Risto mentioned, the best technology for this application is the new BLE audio feature, auracast. It was designed specifically for this use case where one device acts as the broadcaster of LE audio messages, and any listening device would be able to get that message. The problem with auracast and BLE audio in general is that they are relatively new, therefore as of this writing you will not find many devices that have support for this (on the HW or SW level). You might need to wait for a year or more before the use of auracast is widespread.
Below are some relevant links:-

Sending notification to all WiFi devices
Does a WiFi router braodcast messages
Bluetooth technology overview
Bluetooth Low Energy Advertisements
What is Auracast audio sharing tech

